# TextField auto resize issue

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I have the following code in a Codenameone project:

```
final TextArea tf = new TextArea();
tf.setGrowByContent(true);
tf.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
```

The problem is that when I run the app and start typing in such text area, (no matter how many characters) the text area does NOT grow until the focus goes to other widget. My tests have been only in Android.

Is this the "normal" behavior? If not, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal behavior. The text area is native and most native platforms don't have the convention of growing the text area while typing. Instead you can scroll within the text area.

The grow by content flag indicates that the rows/columns value for the text areas preferred size is only a hint and not a limitation, it is on by default so you don't need to invoke this or disable the single line mode (which is only on for `TextField`).